# auto filer - a variable range in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data in excel sheet in range A1 to V150 and having **Subtotal in M156**
Now I want to Autofilter these data as under:
After autofiler, I want to see rows with column A having data greater than "0" and column B should not contain word "yellow"
and of course, Subtotal in M156 must remain there after Autofilter
How it can be done?

Comment: If your answer is not working as you say, delete it and add it to your question by edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub filter()
Dim myrange As Range

Set myrange = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
myrange.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">0"
myrange.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="<>*yellow*"
```

i think that simple code should do. i don't know what you have from rows 151 and 156, if nothing, it will work fine but if you have extra data then you ll have to set up differently myrange

Answer (score -1):

From other buddy's post, I tried as under:

```
Sub FilterTest1()

Dim RngOne As Range, cell As Range
Dim LastCell As Long
Dim arrList() As String, lngCnt As Long

With Sheets("master")
    LastCell = .Range("A" & Sheets("master").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set RngOne = .Range("A1:V" & LastCell)
End With

    ActiveSheet.RngOne.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    ActiveSheet.RngOne.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>yellow"
```